# Перезагрузка блока (div)

Tags: javascript, ajax, битрикс

Существует блок, контент которого подгружается из компонента битрикс `news.list`, перезагружается (содержимое блока) с интервалом в 10 секунд, все нормально. Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы перезагрузка осуществлялась "поверх" имеющихся данных, чтобы не появлялся белый экран. То есть сохранялась предыдущая сессия...и исчезала после подгрузки новой.
Скрипт, отвечающий за перезагрузку:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function(){
    $('.about .bannerSixth').fadeOut('slow').load('index_comanda.php').fadeIn('slow');
}, 10000);
```

Comment: @Marsel Arduanov , спасибо, но не совсем то получается. Нужно, чтобы загрузка была поверх предыдущей итерации. Там блок из картинок, происходит перезагрузка и картинки из в рандомном порядке появляются вновь.

Comment: судя с кода битрикс в тегах можно было и не писать. А вообще просто уберите анимацию или загрузите сначала данные а потом анимируйте уже.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно убрать `fadeOut` и `fadeIn`

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function(){
    $('.about .bannerSixth').load('index_comanda.php');
}, 10000);
```